# How assign roles in the Moodle 3.2

Tags: moodle

I have a problem during I have assign role in **Moodle** don't know which profile have *permission* manage teacher and student?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best if you read through the Moodle documentation: https://docs.moodle.org/33/en/Roles_and_permissions

You can assign a user to a role either System-Wide or context specific, meaning on a course category or on a course itself.